# If I divide feature 1 over feature 2, Do I get feature 3?

Tags: machine-learning, feature-extraction, feature-selection

In features extraction method if I have features f1,f2
If I divide f1/f2 do I get new feature f3, that could enhance model accuracy?

Answer (score 0):

Yes (however, be careful not to divide by 0).

Generally, any non-linear manipulation of your features will produce a new, non-trivial feature that could aid a linear model in doing a better job.
You can also try other simple features such as polynomial features f^d (d=2,3,4..), logarithmic log(f), etc.

Comment: You might also want to check out the [Kernel trick][1], which enables to implicitly use an infinite number of non-linear features.